# SQL instruction in MS Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

The Chr(34) idea gives

```
MsgBox1 SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE JobNumber = BFLA
MsgBox2 "SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE JobNumber = BFLA"
```

which looks as though it should work in OpenRecordset but gives the "can't find table" message for "'SELECT....BFLA'"

The '" & xx & "'" idea gives

```
MsgBox1 SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE JobNumber = 'BFLA'
MsgBox2 "SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE JobNumber = 'BFLA'"
```

which also gives the "can't find table" message for "'SELECT....'BFLA'" (extra single quote before BFLA)

The original code which worked was:

```
xx = Me![JobID]

Set r1 = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from Emp where EmployeeID = " & Nz(Me![JobID]))
```

In this code EmployeeID was a numerical value

The latest code is:

```
xx = Me![JobNumber] ' the JobNumber from the Combo box which is tested in MsgBox 1 and is correct

xxSQL = "SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE JobNumber = '" & xx & "'"

MsgBox xxSQL, vbOKOnly

xxSQL = Chr(34) & xxSQL & Chr(34)

MsgBox xxSQL, vbOKOnly ' which shows what will go into the OpenRecordset

Set r1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(xxSQL)
```

and sorry about the poor formatting last time, hopefully I've got the hang of the message box...

Chris

*****Original message below*****

I am trying to fix some existing Access code because a source application has been changed and I'm really struggling to get a variable into a Select statement into SQL.  I've read many solved problems that are similar to this and tried many permutations of """ before, after and in the middle of this Select, and tried splitting it up.

```
xx = Me![JobNumber]
xxSQL = "SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE JobNumber = " & xx
MsgBox xxSQL, vbOKOnly
xxSQL = """ & xxSQL & """
MsgBox xxSQL, vbOKOnly
Set r1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(xxSQL)
```

The JobNumber is now a 4char string that cycles through various jobs from a Combo Box and produces a report page for each job.  The first MsgBox generates SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE JobNumber = BFLA (a valid code)

Table Emp exists and has a field JobNumber which also contains 4char strings (including BFLA) which match the Me! Combo box.

The second MsgBox produces "& xxSQL &" and then an Access error message - can't find the input table or query "'& xxSQL &"' because I can't get the number and placement of the double quotes right.

The report then generates, repeating the 2 MsgBoxes as it cycles through the Combo box list, and the reports are fine except for missing the content from the Emp table.  There have been no changes to the Emp table other than the introduction of JobNumber, and no changes to the code following the Set r1.

I fear that this is a 2-sec fix for someone with more experience than I, and it will be embarrassing, but I just can't fix it !

Thanks

Chris

Comment: It's a little hard to follow your code as you haven't formatted it, but I think you need to use ansi characters at the second piece of sql.  You have put    xxSQL = """ & xxSQL & """ but I think what you are trying to get is xxSQL = Chr(34) & xxSQL & chr(34).

Comment: Or, if you're trying to compare the text job number with other text, then it needs single quotes around the job number, so your original  "SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE JobNumber = " & xx needs to be xxSQL =  "SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE JobNumber = ' " & xx & " ' "

Comment: Many thanks JennyW and Gustav for the responses.  They look as if they should work but Access still can't find a table that's still there and has only had one field change :(

Comment: If you create a query using your sql what error do you get when you try to execute it?

Comment: The Combo box uses a query to deliver the JobNumbers for matching to the Emp table and it's delivering the right JobNumbers per the MsgBox.  Running a query between the underlying table that feeds the Combo box and the Emp table works happily and delivers the data that I'm wanting in the report....and thanks Jenny

Comment: no problem!  Are you sorted then?  The only thing I was going to say was that I confused you by giving you two options - I meant that you would need one or the other, not both.  From what you have said, I think the single quotes are what you need, as per my comment and Gustav's answer.  Ignore the chr(34) suggestion, and just comment out the code after your first message box.  The xxSQL code you have at that point should be exactly what you need, no further quotations required.

Comment: Hi Jenny.  I tried both separately and then together and the SQL statement doesn't work in any of the 3 possibilities, but the query does and I will have to work out how I can combine the cycling through the combo box aspect into a query and then into the report

Comment: Can you use the query that is used for your combobox to instead filter the underlying recordset for your report by editing the report record source, rather than generating the recordset in vba?

Answer (score 1):

Try this - using quotes as **xx** is text:

```
xx = Me![JobNumber]
xxSQL = "SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE JobNumber = '" & xx & "'"
MsgBox xxSQL, vbOKOnly
Set r1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(xxSQL)
```

Comment: obviously this should be the right answer, but why is it not accepted?